# Dropdown Menu About

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to do a dropdown menu. Cover a distance. But I have a problem. When I click the product menu and opening menu after product menu with the open, click the references menu opening. But click the both menu it can be break down. This problem because of Javascript. Below I share my code also Html and Javascript. I wait for your help.

---**HTML**---

```
<div class="cbp-hsinner">
    <ol class="parent">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Product</a>
            <ol class="child">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/logom.jpg" alt="img01" />
                        <span>Delicate Wine</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/2.png" alt="img02" />
                        <span>Fine Spirit</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/3.png" alt="img03" />
                        <span>Heavenly Ale</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/4.png" alt="img04" />
                        <span>Juicy Lemonade</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/5.png" alt="img05" />
                        <span>Wise Whiskey</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/6.png" alt="img06" />
                        <span>Sweet Rum</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ol>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">References</a>
            <ol class="child">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/1.png" alt="img01" />
                        <span>Delicate Wine</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/2.png" alt="img02" />
                        <span>Fine Spirit</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/3.png" alt="img03" />
                        <span>Heavenly Ale</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/4.png" alt="img04" />
                        <span>Juicy Lemonade</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/5.png" alt="img05" />
                        <span>Wise Whiskey</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/6.png" alt="img06" />
                        <span>Sweet Rum</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

---**JavaScript**---

```
    $('.child').hide();
    $('.parent > li > a').click(function () {         
        $(this).parent().find('.child').slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

Comment: Can you add some more detail to the problem. It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: You code seems fine ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3k6z7hpj/)). What's JS version you are using?

Comment: Jquery 2.0.0.What I using js version?

Comment: Problem When I click product menu.Product menu is opening.Product menu with open when I click the references menu.References menu is opening.Again When I click the References menu then break down.One bye one click menu I have no problem.

Comment: http://test.avrasyademo.xyz/test2/ I did example.Can you look the example.You can understand error.I wait for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide all menu before opening a menu. 
You can use this code.

```
$('.child').hide();
$('.parent > li > a').click(function () {      
    $('.parent').find('.child').hide(); // this will hide menu
    $(this).parent().find('.child').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Does anybody dont know here ?

Comment: http://www.shakeshack.com/ Is there a way I can integrate a sub menu into this? I was looking at Shake Shack’s web menu and was hoping to build a “LOCATION & MENU” drop down menu similar to that.

Comment: http://test.avrasyademo.xyz/test2/ I did example.Can you look the example.You can understand error.I wait for your help.

Comment: Please Mention Your Javascript function then only i can able to help you.

Comment: Did you look my example.Then you can understand this issue.I want to do integrate a sub menu into this.